# How to solve 'COMException not be controlled' caused by MODI (OCR reader)

Tags: c#, ocr, comexception, modi

I'm trying to read an image with MODI (using c#), I followed many of the links that I found on the Internet.

As I can solve the problem "COMException not be controlled" by running the following code:

```
public string reconeixNom(string filePath)
    {
        String nom;

        Document md = new Document(); //Crea document MODI.Document
        md.Create(filePath); //Document amb la ruta que toca.
        md.OCR(MiLANGUAGES.miLANG_SPANISH, false, false);
        MODI.Image image = (MODI.Image)md.Images[0];
        nom = image.Layout.Text;

        image = null;
        md.Close(false);
        md = null;

        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

        return nom;
    }
```

I tried to submit the block in a try-cach capturing the exception

> 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException'

but remains the same.

I have also tried to debug the program, I have found that the exception only spear the following line:

```
md.OCR(MiLANGUAGES.miLANG_SPANISH, false, false);
```

Please, you know where it can be happening?